# How to debug JS calls

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm trying to implement Metronic admin theme in my app, but when I click on a button, I get `Empty string passed to getElementById().` and the buttons don't work.

I'm trying to track down which piece of code triggers this error. How can I find out where the problem is?

Answer (score 6):

write `debugger;` right before the javascript code that you feel is troublesome. Also keep the inspect tools open (usually F12)

This will create a breakpoint in the code execution with which you can then debug your code and look for errors.